# iOS: Hiding sensitive information on the screen when app is backgrounded

Tags: ios, hipaa, backgrounding

When a foreground app gets backgrounded (e.g. Home button gets pressed), how can I change elements on the topmost view controller *prior* to when iOS takes a snapshot of it and starts the animation to show the next screen?

I ask because I'm writing an app requiring HIPAA compliance, and I am concerned that the snapshot that the OS takes in order to do this animation sometimes contains sensitive data which should *not* be visible even for a split second when the app gets foregrounded later.

I'm aware that view controllers have lifecycle methods such as `viewWillDisappear` which might be usable, but I have a lot of controllers and I'd rather just have something in my App Delegate to handle this (e.g. by adding an opaque full-screen UIImageView overlay) rather than having to write custom code for this in every last controller.

I tried putting overlay-generating code in `applicationWillResignActive`, and I've been digging with Apple's docs and Google, but it's not working.  I suspect the screenshot gets taken before the app has a chance to update the screen.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried changing the views in `applicationWillEnterForeground`? Or is that also a static animation until the entire resume zoom animation is done?

Comment: Well, it's working now.  I'm not sure if it's because I added my `UIImageView` to `self.window` rather than pulling the `topViewController` out of my `navigationController` and adding it there, or if it's because I put the code in `applicationDidEnterBackground` rather than `applicationWillResignActive`.  Anyway, the sensitive info is no longer displayed when foregrounding.  I'll try to dig into this and write a more concise answer as soon as SO will let me.

Comment: Without being fully up on HIPAA compliance, is it going to be an issue that users can take screenshots at any time? There's no known solution to that as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Good thought, Tommy.  We don't expect this to be an issue in our case.  Staff will either have full control over the iPad and will be educated on this issue, or it will be in a kiosk enclosure so patients can't access the power button.  IIRC, the Photos app can also be forbidden using security settings.  Will have to R&D that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer is to not concern oneself with changing what's on the screen *before* the backgrounding animation begins, but to simply modify what's displayed on the screen once the app enters the background (i.e. inside of `applicationDidEnterBackground:` in your App Delegate.)  This solved my problem.

My `UIImageView` overlay idea worked here, although I decided just to pop to the root view controller instead.  Simpler that way.  My root view doesn't have any sensitive info.

Here's what it looks like:

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    UINavigationController *navigationController = 
        (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    [navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about HIPAA's requirements about backgrounding and possibly leaving the user logged in for someone else to resume, but the safest sounds like it would be to add a key `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` with a boolean value of `YES` to `info.plist`.

That will prevent the app from backgrounding entirely, and restarts it (possibly triggering a login procedure) every time you go back to it.

Most (if not all) mobile banking applications I've tested do this for safety reasons.

Comment: That's a good idea, although I already found a solution that lets me keep backgrounding.  Good as a last resort though.