# How can I view the snapshot image that iOS takes when app goes to background?

Tags: ios

When an iOS app enters background, a snapshot of the last screen is taken and placed in the cache. How do I view this image to ensure that sensitive information from the app is not accidentally stored in the cache?

I checked XCode organizer but I cant find a tool to open and view the cache.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You can [take screenshot programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200736/how-to-take-a-screenshot-programmatically)  and check its content in `- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application` in AppDelegate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry about viewing the image - just make sure you won't show any sensitive information.

The OS will trigger a call to your application delegate's [`(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) method. Use that to hide any information you need to. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12612380/264775) to a post concerning HIPAA requirements for an iOS app - you can pop to your root view so the app will resume somewhere without sensitive information.

Comment: I was able to confirm that screen shot is not capturing any sensitive information by running the app in the iPhone/iPad simulator and examining the png stored to 

~/Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/<App GUID>/Library/Caches/Snapshots/<app id>

use open -a preview <name of png>.png to view the snapshot

Answer (score 2):

For a handy way to get the simulator folder put a breakpoint somewhere in code, then in Xcode debugger:

```
po NSHomeDirectory()
```

In Terminal ->

```
cd <pathfromabove>/Library/Caches/Snapshots/<yourappid>
```

then

```
ls
```

to see all the snapshots.. and then as mentioned in comment below question..

```
open -a preview <whatevernameofsnapshot>
```