# Securing app view when in iphone app is in background (keywindow)?

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I have an app that needs to be secured when the app is in the background. I also noticed my Ally bank app does the same thing. When you have the Ally bank app open, but then put it in the background by double click the home button, while still viewing the Ally bank app. This will shrink the app. The Ally bank app then covers the key window screen shot in all purple, so you can't see bank account information.

Does anyone know how they are doing this? Am I off base by assuming its the keyWindow snapshot?

TIA

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS: Hiding sensitive information on the screen when app is backgrounded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589108/ios-hiding-sensitive-information-on-the-screen-when-app-is-backgrounded)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792850/display-a-view-or-splash-screen-before-applicationdidenterbackground-to-avoid-a